# Make an absolutely positioned child element visible when parent (level-2) has overflow-hidden

Tags: css, overflow

I want to make the inner absolutely positioned element visible, when parent (level-2) element has overflow property set to hidden.

P.S.: z-index does not work

Codepen: http://codepen.io/mstoic/pen/gpqVKo?editors=110

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 5em;
  background: #6c3;
  display: block;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -2em;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So why are you setting the overflow to hidden if you want the child to show?

Comment: Actually this is just a small test case. The parent div contains 100s of HTML elements, which can disturb the layout. This is why overflow is set to hidden.

Comment: Soooo... What was your question?

Comment: Say the parent div contains 10 divs which display dynamic content. They can contain anything which can break the layout. That is why I have set the overflow hidden property on outer div. Now for one div, I want to display the overflowed content whatsover. This div basically contains the tooltip, which only appears on mouseover.

Comment: I confess I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do here. Perhaps a better demo that shows a full use case?

Comment: @mstoic - Is there a reason that you cannot use `position:absolute;` to remove your child elements from the flow and `display:none;`  to hide them until you are ready for them to be shown? That way you do not have to use `overflow:hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend splitting the parent into 2 divs, one to store elements you want cropped and one to store elements you want to overlap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">    
    <div class="parent-wrapper">
        <!-- Put elements you want cropped in here -->
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <!-- Put elements you don't want cropped in here -->
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {

    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 5em;
    background: #6c3;
    display: block;
}
.parent-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: -2em;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqLYYB?editors=110)

Comment: According to my use case, the element needs to go in the 'parent' itself. There are many other elements, all of which have to go to a single parent. And from those elements I just want this element to be displayed even if overflow-hidden is used.

Comment: You can't effect a parent's style from a child like that. If the overflow is set to hidden, all elements in it that overflow are going to be hidden. You may want to consider using something like what IMI suggested in the comments and set the elements you don't want seen to `display: none`.

Answer (score -1):

If the parent is in position static, if you set position absolute to the child it will be removed from the flow :

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D : The question is "Make an absolutely positioned child element visible when parent (level-2) has overflow-hidden". An absolutely positioned child element is visible if the parent which have the overflow:hidden property is in position:static.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter ... I edited with a second level parent for you, but the mechanic is the same.

Comment: I explained that the parents need to be in position static to show the absolute positioned children. That's the whole point of my answer. Maybe I 'm not clear enough, english is not my native language.

Comment: And the point of the OP's question is that they *aren't* positioned static...so you're not really solving his problem. You're just saying "don't do it that way". Perhaps if you added "It's not possible" and explained **why** it's not possible then the answer might be improved,

Comment: I read again and I don't see where he said that .child MUST have postion:relative. If his code doesn't work is because of that, so yeah, I give him a way to make it work and I even explain why (the parents should be in position:static to make it work). Maybe here is a better way to achieve what he wants, I just gave him a clue, but I can't do it better unless he give more details ...

Comment: This isn't really a solution, you're just positioning the child absolutely on the page rather than relative to the box it's contained in.

Comment: The question is "make an absolutely positionned child-element visible ..."